# SQL SERVER to DATA FACTORY the request limit for the database is 120 and has been reached

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an SQL server database linked to azure data factory.  when I sometimes run a query on a table.  I get the following pop up error message, but the table still runs.

> error unable to apply connection settings the detailed error message is resource id...the request limit for the database is 120 and has been reached

Comment: It seems that you have more than 120 concurrent connections to your database. Perhaps your application is leaking database connections? i.e.: it's not closing connections when finished querying on them or not returning them to the Connection Pool.

Comment: Do you on-premis SQL Server or Azure SQL database? If it's Azure SQL database, what's the price tier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by going into data factory → pipeline → copy data object → source tab, and changing the 120-seconds timeout limit to 240 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the performance of your query. You can first check for any performance improvements and then if that doesn't solve the problem then you can try increasing the tier as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-single-databases#single-database-storage-sizes-and-compute-sizes)

Comment: Hi @R2D2 : If my response helped you, can you please upvote it so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !